# cmake: How to link subdirectory library by ignoring sysroot library?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile an application for a different platform (quark processor) using cmake. The platform has provided an SDK to me. My application requires a newer version of one of the libraries in the SDK. I have added the new source code for the library using add_subdirectory(). But my problem is when I use target_link_libraries(), cmake is linking the older version of the library in my SDK. How to enable cmake ignore the library version in the SDK sysroot, and only use the new library version present in the subdirectory?

Edit: My apologies for the initial lack of details.Adding more details to the question as suggested.
My CMakeLists.txt include the following statements

```
add_subdirectory(libs/mosquitto-1.4.10)  
target_link_libraries(myapp mosquittopp)
```

As mentioned, my problem is that the SDK I am using contains a 1.4 version of mosquitto library. The target_link_libraries() only links the 1.4 version and not the newer 1.4.10 version, even though cmake successfully builds the 1.4.10 version.

Comment: Imagine someone asking you this question, would you have been able to help them? Come on! Seriously! Post examples of the code with a minimal, verifiable and complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist apologies if my question wasn't very clear. Added more details as suggested.

Comment: With [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) you may provide **full path** to the library for link with. Alternatively, if you now the name of the library **target**, you may use that name instead - CMake will extract full path to the library from the target's properties.

Comment: Going in the direction Tsyvarev suggested, it might help to answer if you share the CMakeLists.txt in the directory libs/mosquitto-1.4.10